# Can't connect to 802.1x EAP network in recent Ubuntu versions

Tags: wireless, 12.10, 14.04, atheros, ralink

In my college there's a WiFi network using 802.1x PEAP. In Ubuntu 12.10 and older, I can sucessfully connect to it, but in Ubuntu 13.04, 13.10 and 14.04, it keeps asking for password and never connect.

At first I thought it was a problem with my Ralink RT5390 WiFi card as it doesn't have good open-source support and other friend were having trouble connecting to the same network with Ralink cards. So I got an Atheros AR5B22 and it solved a lot of small isues I was getting (including connecting to this netowrk), but I'm stuck in Ubuntu 12.10 because of this. Is there something I can do to get that network working in current versions, like 14.04 or it's a know bug?

I'm not sure what kind of technical info you guys need, so, just ask me if necessary...

Comment: Do you have dmesg error messages about the authentication? Are you running nm-applet as root or as normal user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know a workaround 
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2168015,
try to remove

```
[802-1x]
system-ca-certs=true  <--THIS LINE
```

in the file:

```
/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/[Your connection]
```

Comment: I'm not sure why this was voted down. I use 802.1x on multiple linux boxes, and I usually have to apply the fix above to get it to work.